# Checking library integrity

Tags: c++, compilation

I created a script to remove useless code in many c++ libs (like ifdefs, comments, etc.)

Now, I want to compare the original lib and the "treated" lib to check if my script has done a good job.

The only solution I found is to compare the exported symbols.

I'm wondering if you have any other ideas to check the integrity?

Comment: If I scripted this it's because I need too treat a LARGE (more than 100 libs (~ 100k files)) amount of code. Some of them had unit tests but I can't create unit test for each of them.. I have 1 month, not 1 year...

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like an unrealistic requirement (and why remove comments?) And again, `#fdef`s? the compiler does this for you already. This sort of thing should be done opportunistically, not in one fell swoop and definitely not via a script. C++ is a notoriously difficult language to parse correctly... IMHO I would not modify 100k files in one go without suitable tests, you're looking to get fired...

Comment: Ahah, yes. You're right but.. I don't choose what I have to do.. It's a part of my mission, and the other part is not better... And I hope i'll not be fired, because this is what they ask me to do..

Answer (score 1):

FIRST of all: Unit tests are designed for this purpose.

---

You might get some mileage out of

- compiling without optimization (`-O0`) and without debug information (or `strip` it afterwards)
- [`objdump`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_objdump.htm) `-dCS`

and compare the disassemblies. Prepare to meet some / many spurious errors (the `strip` step was there to prevent needless differences in source line number info). In particular you will have to

- ignore addresses
- ignore generated label names

But if the transformation would really lead to unmodified code, you'd be able to verify it 1:1 using this technique and a little work.

Answer (score 0):

assert based unit test would help you. Have some test cases , run them against the original library and then run with the code removed .